# How to put my results(output) in a 2D list or a nested list after a "for loop"?

Tags: python

For example, I have a 2D list of grades for three student. The teacher decided to add 10 points to all grades. We have the following code:

```
grades = [[90,95,100],[80,82,84],[20,30,40]]
new_grades = []
for i in range(len(grades)):
    for j in range(len(grades[i])):
        idv_grades = grades[i][j]+10
        new_grades.append(idv_grades)
```

The resulting list new_grades gives out: [100, 105, 110, 90, 92, 94, 30, 40, 50].

What I want is the original 2D list format:[[100, 105, 110],[90, 92, 94] ,[30, 40, 50]]

When I put new_grades[i].append(idv_grades), it gives out IndexError: list index out of range. I know I can manually reshape/separate these values, but I have a huge complex 2D list in my original problem. I would like to know how to separate it within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
grades = [[90,95,100],[80,82,84],[20,30,40]]
new_grades = []
for i in range(len(grades)):
    for j in range(len(grades[i])):
        idv_grades = grades[i][j]+10
    new_grades.append(idv_grades)
```

Answer (score 1):

For each iteration of the `for i in range(len(grades))` loop, you can create a separate list to store the changed values from that sublist, like so:

```
grades = [[90,95,100],[80,82,84],[20,30,40]]
new_grades = []
for i in range(len(grades)):
    sublist = []
    for j in range(len(grades[i])):
        idv_grades = grades[i][j]+10
        sublist.append(idv_grades)
    new_grades.append(sublist)
```

In the above code, `sublist` will be defined each iteration of the outer loop. The inner loop will append the changed grade values to `sublist`, after which `sublist` will be appended to `new_grades`.

In other words, in each iteration of the outer loop, `sublist` is the updated form of one of the inner `grades` lists. Each `sublist` is appended to `new_grades`, keeping the original 2D format.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider doing a list comprehension:

```
grades = [[90,95,100],[80,82,84],[20,30,40]]
new_grades = []
for i in range(len(grades)):
    idv_grades = [grade + 10 for grade in grades[i]]
    new_grades.append(idv_grades)
```

Note that this removed one the `j` for loop.

```py
In [13]: new_grades                                                                                                                 
Out[13]: [[100, 105, 110], [90, 92, 94], [30, 40, 50]]
```

Comment: Note that I'm appending a `list` here, so this is the way to get a list of lists. I think this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is good to use `map` function, `map` function iterates over `grades` array (each student grades) and generate edited array for each student.

```
grades = [[90, 95, 100], [80, 82, 84], [20, 30, 40]]
result = list(map(lambda x: [i + 10 for i in x], grades))
print(result)
```

output:

```
[[100, 105, 110], [90, 92, 94], [30, 40, 50]]
```